# Robotframework.request - How to make a POST request with content “multipart/form-data” and a Key value

Tags: java, python, python-requests, robotframework

I want to make a POST request in Robot Framework with "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" using the HttpRequestLibrary but it doesn't work for me.

The curl of the request is:

```
curl -X POST "https://xxx-approuter-xxx-xxxxxx" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "pkcsFile=" -F "crtFile=" -F "privateKey=" -F "jsonBody={'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}"
```

The problem I have with that is I don't know where and how jsonBody variable should be defined with robot scripr. It does work in Postman properly, because in request's body, I can choose form-data and then define key as jsonBody and it's value as

```
{'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}
```

Below is example of my Robot script:

```
${headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=multipart/form-data  Authorization=${token}
${data}=  Create Dictionary  jsonBody={'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}
${resp}=    Post Request   my_session   /authentications  data=${data}  headers=${headers}
```

returns error:

```
"message": "Required AuthenticationDto parameter jsonBody is not present"
```

Can anybody help me with this or drop a proper example of how to use HttpRequestLibrary with Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get this json:

```
{'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}
```

Your Dictionary syntax is incorrect

Change:

```
${data}=  Create Dictionary  jsonBody={'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}
```

which gives  results:

```
{'jsonBody': "{'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}"}
```

TO :

```
${data}=  Create Dictionary   method=BASIC_AUTH  username=xxx  password=xxx
```

which gives results

```
{'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to get this string

```
jsonBody={'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}
```

What you are trying to do is, You are using `jsonBody=${var}` robot framework will take jsonBody as the first key of the dictionary creating a nested dictionary what you need is a string before your dictonary.

You can use catanate to join the string together

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
        ${jsonBody} =  Set variable  jsonBody
        ${data}=  Create Dictionary   method=BASIC_AUTH  username=xxx  password=xxx
        ${finishedbody} =  Catenate   ${jsonBody}=${data}
        log  ${finishedbody}
```

Results

```
${finishedbody} =    jsonBody={'method': 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username': 'xxx', 'password': 'xxx'}
```

Comment: Now I have error: "message": "Multipart request resolution failed. Please ensure that each part is properly formatted." So this jsonBody key value is still missing , but I have to provide it

Comment: @DimaZeuge are you trying to get this result as your json? `{'method' = 'BASIC_AUTH', 'username' = 'xxx', 'password' = 'xxxxx'}`

Comment: @Wojtej T , If you check curl above, you will see that I need 
"jsonBody={
  "method": "MUTUAL_AUTH",
  "password": "secret"
}"

jsonBody is key and son is a value. Please check the full script above...I don't understand what's wrong with it...

${data}= Create Dictionary method=BASIC_AUTH username=xxx password=xxx and then 
${data}= Create Dictionary jsonBody=${var}

Comment: @Wojtej T, I have tried, but it didn't work, I am still getting "Multipart request resolution failed. Please ensure that each part is properly formatted."  error message

Comment: @DimaZeuge  Please refer this page , I believe you will get your answer though its too late https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462955/robotframework-request-how-to-make-a-post-request-with-content-multipart-form

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I came to this scenario, but it fails as well:

```
Creates an authentication schema
    [Arguments]   ${providerType}  ${providerMode}  ${pkcsFile}  ${returnStatus}
    ${headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=multipart/form-data  Authorization=${jwt_token}
    ${data}=  Create Dictionary   method=BASIC_AUTH  username=xxx  password=xxx
    ${formData}=  Create Dictionary   jsonBody=${data}
    Log  ${formData}
    ${resp}=    Post Request   httpbin    /configuration/test/test/tests  data=${formData}  headers=${headers}
    Log  ${resp}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    ${returnStatus}
```

And the result is:

```
"message": "Multipart request resolution failed. Please ensure that each part is properly formatted."
```

I have to provide key value jsonBody somehow, but I am not sure if I did it correct