# Robot Framework “multipart/form-data” REST request with multiple parameters

Tags: python-requests, robotframework

I am trying to use requestslibrary to upload some files, goal is to achieve this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary61N9vqJ7380nh6iv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="photo-2.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary61N9vqJ7380nh6iv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileId"

b3duLWZpbGVzL2ZmZmZmZmZmYTQyNDVmODAvMjAxNTY*
------WebKitFormBoundary61N9vqJ7380nh6iv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="extract"

false
------WebKitFormBoundary61N9vqJ7380nh6iv--
```

and now I have this, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462955/robotframework-request-how-to-make-a-post-request-with-content-multipart-form):

```
  ${data}=    Evaluate    {'files': open("C:/testautomation/resources/Assets/photo-2.jpeg", 'r+b'), 'extract': (None, 'false'), 'fileId': (None, 'b3duLWZpbGVzL2ZmZmZmZmZmYTQyNDVmODAvMjAxNTY*')}
  log  ${data}
  ${result}=  Post Request  rest  ${url}  headers=${HEADERS}  files=${data}
```

I *THINK* that the only bit I am missing is the "Content-Type: image/jpeg" from the first part, but how on earth I can add that? Currently the file gets uploaded, but it is not considered to be an image file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was:

```
${data}=  Evaluate  {'files': ('photo-1.jpeg', open("C:/testautomation-robot/resources/Assets/photo-1.jpeg", 'r+b'), 'image/jpeg'), 'extract': (None, 'false'), 'fileId': (None, 'b3duLWZpbGVzL2ZmZmZmZmZmYTQyNDVmODAvMjAxNTY*')}
```

Found an example from here: https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/bcfb9b

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
In the above, the tuple is composed as follows:

(filename, data, content_type, headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a python resources and call it through robot framework:
[image: Create a python resources] and call it through robot framework

Call params from `robotframework`:
upload multipart files post request  ${headers}  ${url}  resources/files/upload_file/testfile1_upload.pdf