Form data as text in body using robot framework
Formdata usage in postman
above is the attached image
how to send form data in the above way using robot framework
i tried with all types of examples available but unable to send the form data correctly with robot framework
Create Session    session    https://wismaapapidev.tanla.co.in templateapi/v1/bots

${data}=             Create Dictionary    name=test_template3    type=text    textMessage=Hi there!
${template_data}=    Set Variable    {"name": "test_template3", "type": "text", "textMessage": "Hi there"}
${headers}=          Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json    Authorization=Bearer ${token}
${response}=         POST On Session    session    /JaAsM3ezSOjpVxoA/templates    json=${template_data}    headers=${headers}

Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.status_code}    200

i am getting the error like "request body doesnot contain multipart/form-data"

Hi @lakshmi priyanka, not exactly sure that the problem is but could it be because your ${template_data} is not a dictionary variable? If you look at the POST documentation, it says If you want to pass a json body pass a dictionary as json parameter.. You could try creating the ${template_data} variable like the ${data} variable that you have created and see if it works.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462955/robotframework-request-how-to-make-a-post-request-with-content-multipart-form and the answer there might help. It really depends on the server implementation..

Few points, You are explicitly setting the content-type to application/json  but server is expecting multi-part. Second, you are passing your content to json argument, which will post it as json to the server.  With multi-part as content-type, actual body of payload could be a different than just posting a json file..
